# Error when running qbittorent on my arch based machine

Tags: linux, qt, archlinux

When I run qbittorent on my arch based machine (Arcolinux) I get the follow error :-

```
 qbittorrent: /usr/lib/libQt6Core.so.6: version `Qt_6.3' not found (required by qbittorrent)
```

Here's the output on running `qmake --version`

```
$ qmake --version
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.15.2 in /usr/lib
```

I would be much obliged if someone helped me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install qbittorrent? There is actually package "qbittorrent" in official repos.

Use `sudo pacman -S qbittorrent` to install it with all necessary dependencies.

Or just install needed dependencies. To see all dependencies, use `pacman -Qi qbittorrent`. The output (sorry for Russian language):

```
Название             : qbittorrent
Версия               : 4.4.3.1-2
Описание             : An advanced BitTorrent client programmed in C++, based on Qt toolkit and libtorrent-rasterbar
Архитектура          : x86_64
URL                  : https://www.qbittorrent.org
Лицензии             : custom  GPL
Группы               : Нет
Предоставляет        : Нет
Зависит от           : libtorrent-rasterbar  qt6-base  qt6-svg  hicolor-icon-theme //<- this is the dependencies
Доп. зависимости     : python: needed for torrent search tab [установлено]
Требуется            : Нет
Опционально для      : Нет
Конфликтует с        : Нет
Заменяет             : Нет
Установленный размер : 9,34 MiB
Сборщик              : Antonio Rojas <arojas@archlinux.org>
Дата сборки          : Пт 27 мая 2022 19:26:27
Дата установки       : Сб 28 мая 2022 00:28:46
Причина установки    : Явно установлен
Установочный скрипт  : No
Проверен             : Подпись
```

As you can see, the dependencies are `libtorrent-rasterbar`, `qt6-base`, `qt6-svg`, `hicolor-icon-theme`. It seems that you have to install qt6. But for reliability I advice you to reinstall all those packages with `sudo pacman -S libtorrent-rasterbar qt6-base qt6-svg hicolor-icon-theme`. And even better way is to just reinstall qbittorrent with `sudo pacman -S qbittorrent` as mentioned above. All dependencies will be installed automatically. And also they will be marked as dependencies, not as intentionally installed packages, which is better.